# VBA Acess -- Caja de Lista (ListBox)

Tags: vba, ms-access

Quiero hacer que una Caja de Lista (ListBox) en Access 2010 no tenga ningún elemento seleccionado al darle a un botón del formulario.

¿Qué código de VBA podría darle para hacer esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pon la propiedad Value en 0.

Cuando hay un item seleccionado en un ListBox, la propiedad `Value` devuelve el nº de columna dependiente. Si devuelve 0, es que no se ha seleccionado nada en el Listbox.

Pero la propiedad es de lectura y escritura, así que si fuerzas que sea 0, elimina la selección.

Prueba esto en el código de tu botón.

```
Me.Listbox.Value = 0
```

> Más info en [Propiedad ListBox.Value
>   (acceso)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/vba/access-vba/articles/listbox-value-property-access)

Comment: Exacto! Eso ha funcionado muy bien. También poniendo "Null" como valor, que me imagino que será equivalente.