# Ejecutar un evento de manera dinámica

Tags: vba

Necesitaría poder ejecutar eventos de manera dinámica.

Mas concretamente, quiero conseguir un método que sea capaz de vaciar un control cualquiera. Pero para ello, no solo necesito poner el campo a NULL, sino que también necesitaría ejecutar el evento AfterUpdate de ese control.

Una idea simplificada para un solo formulario, sería hacer algo así:

```
Private Function BorrarContenido(byval NombreControl as String)
    Me.controls(NombreControl) = Null
    CAll NombreControl & "_AfterUpdate"
End Sub
```

Por supuesto, esto no funciona. Pero creo que es fácil de entender lo que necesitaría.

Por la red conseguí ver que el método Application.Run sería capaz de llamar a un método pasado como una cadena. Pero no es capaz de llamar a un evento de un formulario, así que tampoco me sirvió.

La alternativa de usar un SELECT CASE tampoco me vale. Este método quiero que sea lo más genérico posible. Así que hacer algo como lo que sigue no me serviría:

```
Private Function BorrarContenido(Byval NombreControl as string)
     me.Controls(NombreControl) = Null

     Select Case NombreControl
         Case "Control1": Call Control1_AfterUpdate
         Case "Control2": Call Control2_AfterUpdate
         ...
         Case "ControlN": Call ControlN_AfterUpdate
End Sub
```

Alguna idea?

NOTA:
Buscando por internet, suelo encontar las respuestas del tipo "y para que quieres hacer esto?".
Suponed unos 200 formularios dentro de mi proyecto. Todos repletos de controles, combos y demás
Ahora suponed que quiero dar una funcionalidad general al programa. Si el usuario hace doble clic sobre un control, este se borrará (y a su vez debe refrescar otros datos que estuvieran relacionados con ese control)

Cuando adapte cualquier formulario, querría añadir a cada control que me interese resetear, una redirección del evento DblClick al método BorrarContenido()

```
Control.OnDblClick = "BorrarContenido()"
```

Y solo con eso, despreocuparme de programar nada adicional. El método debería ser capaz de poner a Null el control, y de ejecutar el evento AfterUpdate.

Comment: Los eventos, tanto para las hojas, libros como formularios se ejecutan automáticamente cuando la condición se cumple, es decir, `After_Update` se ejecutaría tras actualizar el formulario, sin hacer nada más. A menos que tengas `Application.EnableEvents = False` lo que deberías hacer genérico es lo de `BorrarContenido` pero los eventos se cargan solos.

Comment: Lo sé. Pero cuando se actualiza un control por código, el evento no se ejecuta. Por ello necesito forzar que ese evento se ejecute, y que sea independiente del control vaciado (tal y como planteé en mi duda inicial)

Answer (score 0):

No estoy muy seguro de si esto te servirá, pero allá vamos.

Yo he hecho un formulario con un `Textbox1`.

Tiene un código en el evento `dlbClic`

```
Private Sub TextBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Call Módulo1.BORRO_CONTENIDO(Me.ActiveControl)
End Sub
```

He insertado un módulo que se llama `Módulo1` y que tiene este código:

```
Public Sub BORRO_CONTENIDO(ByVal mictl As Control)
mictl.Value = Null
End Sub
```

Esto hace que el Textbox al hacer DobleClick se vacíe.

Es un ejemplo burdo, pero te puede servir para montar lo tuyo. Creo que dentro del evento público `BORRO_CONTENIDO` sí deberás personalizar dependiendo de si el control es un TextBox o un ComboBox o un Listbox (por ejemplo, [creo que los Listbox se vacían así](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/188377/vba-acess-caja-de-lista-listbox/188537#188537).

Para diferenciar de dónde vienes, puedes usar la propiedad `Tag`, que es común a esos 3 tipos de control.

Te dejo enlace a un ejemplo de la propiedad `Tag` que explica cómo usarla.
[Ejemplo de propiedad Tag](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/tag-property-example)

Para asignarle valor, en el Editor de VBA, abajo a la izquierda en el visor de propiedades, lo puedes personalizar para cada control (tienes que seleccionar antes el control).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En tu caso, sería crearte 3 tags en plan TXT,CMB y LTB. Dependiendo de la tag, querrás vaciar el control de una manera o de otra.

Entonces la macro que vacíe el contenido tendrá una estructura parecida a esto:

```
Public Sub BORRO_CONTENIDO(ByVal mictl As Control)

Select Case mictl.Tag
    Case "TXT"
        mictl.Value = Null
    Case "LTB"
        mictl.Value = 0
    Case "CMB"
        'código para vaciar un Combobox
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Falta etiqueta", vbCritical, "ERROR"
End Select



End Sub
```

Lo de llamar al evento AfterUpdate ya es más complicado, porque cada uno tiene el suyo. Pero si fuerzas un terminate, se activa el evento `AfterUpdate`del control. Dale una vuelta a ver qué consigues.

Comment: Como inicializar contenido es un tema que no tiene que ver con la duda que planteé, aunque agradezco el esfuerzo.
Saliendo de mi tema, te comento que puedes saber el tipo de control de una manera más elegante. Puedes usar `me.ActiveControl.ControlType`, y compararlo con `acComboBox`, `acListBox` o `acTextBox`. O también puedes usar: `If typeof me.activecontrol is ComboBox/ListBox/TextBox then`

Comment: Mi necesidad se centra en el último párrafo que pusiste (llamar a un evento `AfterUpdate` de un control dinámicamente). Respecto a forzar un `Terminate`, he buscado información, pero no veo como podría ayudarme.